# Trying to connect to shairplay from itunes

Tags: raspbian, audio, media-server

I have successfully connected to shairplay on windows from ITunes on a MacBook Air.

I have compiled and installed shairport on the PI and ran it as a service. But even after restarting the MacBook, I can't see it listed in remote speakers in ITunes.

I don't know how to debug this. I can't see any obvious processes that would indicate a shairport server, even though this is what I did:

```
@raspberrypi ~/Downloads/albertz-shairport-4746bb1 $ sudo insserv shairport

@raspberrypi ~/Downloads/albertz-shairport-4746bb1 $ sudo service avahi-daemon start
[ ok ] Starting Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Daemon: avahi-daemon.

@raspberrypi ~/Downloads/albertz-shairport-4746bb1 $ sudo /etc/init.d/shairport start
[ ok ing shairport: .\
```

I need a few pointers to troubleshoot this.

Comment: I've got the same problem, My Raspberry was working fine untill i wanted to update it because sometimes shairplay crashed. Now after installing everything, it doesn't work. i've got [ ok ing shairport: . after i started it but then nothing, it's not viewable from Itunes or my Ipod and if i do a "ps" it's not shown (but maybe it's normal for this one) Hope we're going to find what the problem is!!
Are you using a Usb dongle for the sound? Sorry for my english, it's not my natural language

Comment: I was using the standard analog output for the sound. I can play sound using `mpg123` but I have the same shairport behaviour as you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install Net::SDP, otherwise Shairplay won't start..

```
run perl -MCPAN -s shell 
Set up accepting the defaults
type install Net::SDP
```